# Issues with Promise() not delaying function until Animation has completed

Tags: javascript, promise, css-animations, fadeout

I've read about how to use `promise();` but can't seem to get it to let the animation play out before executing my promise function, at the moment it runs the 3 games then suddenly hides all the elements, have I missed some code out that is required for the promise api?

```
function runTheGames(){
var myEvent = function(){
       $('.board2').fadeOut({duration : "slow"});
       $('.board').fadeOut({duration : "slow"});
       $('.control').fadeOut({duration: "slow"});
       $("h2").fadeOut({duration: "slow"});
       $("h3").fadeOut({duration: "slow"});
    }
  $.when(myEvent()).promise().done(function(){
        isTraining = true;
        var xPlayer = new AI("master");
        var oPlayer = new AI("menace");
        if(isTraining === true){
            for(var count = 0; count < 3; count++){
                var training = new Training(xPlayer, oPlayer);
                xPlayer.plays(training);                     
                oPlayer.plays(training);
                training.start();
            }
         }
         isTraining = false;
         $(".cell").html("");
         $(".bead").html("");
         console.log("FINISHED TRAINING");
     });
}
```

Comment: 1) Won't `isTraining` always be true when you reach the `if (isTraining === true)`? Unless it changes in the `AI` constructor. 2) Just say `if (isTraining)`, unless you need to be sure that `isTraining` is not some other truthy value.

Comment: it does change in AI and other UI elements trigger off that boolean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jquery animation api to achieve this by providing a callback function to your animations.

```
var myEvent = function(){
    $('.board2').fadeOut("slow");
    $('.board').fadeOut({"slow");
    $('.control').fadeOut("slow");
    $("h2").fadeOut("slow");
    $("h3").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        // animations are completed here
        afterEvent();
    });
};

var afterEvent = function() {
    isTraining = true;
    var xPlayer = new AI("master");
    var oPlayer = new AI("menace");
    if(isTraining === true){
        for(var count = 0; count < 3; count++){
            var training = new Training(xPlayer, oPlayer);
            xPlayer.plays(training);                     
            oPlayer.plays(training);
            training.start();
        }
    }
    isTraining = false;
    $(".cell").html("");
    $(".bead").html("");
    console.log("FINISHED TRAINING");
};
```

Hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the promise statement outside of myEvent function expression like so:

```js
function runTheGames(){
  
  var myEvent = function(){
     $('.board2').fadeOut({duration : "slow"});
     $('.board').fadeOut({duration : "slow"});
     $('.control').fadeOut({duration: "slow"});
     $("h2").fadeOut({duration: "slow"});
     $("h3").fadeOut({duration: "slow"});
    }
  }

  $.when(myEvent()).promise().done(function(){
    isTraining = true;
    var xPlayer = new AI("master");
    var oPlayer = new AI("menace");
    if(isTraining === true){
      for(var count = 0; count < 3; count++){
        var training = new Training(xPlayer, oPlayer);
        xPlayer.plays(training);                     
        oPlayer.plays(training);
        training.start();
      }
     }
     isTraining = false;
     $(".cell").html("");
     $(".bead").html("");
     console.log("FINISHED TRAINING");
   });

}
```

Comment: The promise is outside of the `myEvent` function, his indentation is just off and I can't edit it because the suggested edit queue is full.

Answer (score 0):

The function *myEvent* is actually returning *undefined*!

If you don't know the number of promises, you can use *apply* to send *when's* argument as an *array*, so you could pass it an *array of promises*.

You can also use *myEvent* to return the array of promises, the method *promise* return a promise that is resolved when the animation es being done.

Check the comments within the code.

```
function runTheGames(){
var myEvent = function(){
       var promises = [] // We initialize an empty array
       promises.push($('.board2').fadeOut({duration : "slow"}).promise())
       promises.push($('.board').fadeOut({duration : "slow"}).promise())
       promises.push($('.control').fadeOut({duration: "slow"}).promise())
       promises.push($("h2").fadeOut({duration: "slow"}).promise())
       promises.push($("h3").fadeOut({duration: "slow"}).promise())
       // We keep pushing all the promises to the array
       return promises; // We return the array of promises
    }

  $.when.apply($, myEvent()) // We create a promise that is resolved when a set of promises are resolved (in this case, the ones returned by myEvent)
  .done(function(){
        isTraining = true;
        var xPlayer = new AI("master");
        var oPlayer = new AI("menace");
        if(isTraining === true){
            for(var count = 0; count < 3; count++){
                var training = new Training(xPlayer, oPlayer);
                xPlayer.plays(training);                     
                oPlayer.plays(training);
                training.start();
            }
         }
         isTraining = false;
         $(".cell").html("");
         $(".bead").html("");
         console.log("FINISHED TRAINING");
     });
}
```